# How to correctly typecast char array to struct pointer?

Tags: c, memory

I'm new to C language. The following code snippet is from a book I've been reading.

```
struct S {
  int i; double d; char c;
};

int main(void) {
  unsigned char bad_buff[sizeof(struct S)];
  _Alignas(struct S) unsigned char good_buff[sizeof(struct S)];

  struct S *bad_s_ptr = (struct S *)bad_buff;   // wrong pointer alignment
  struct S *good_s_ptr = (struct S *)good_buff; // correct pointer alignment
}
```

The author states that `bad_buff` may have incorrect alignment for member-access expressions. I have difficulty in understanding this statement. What can go wrong if we use `bad_buff` ?

Comment: Is this really from a book? Both methods are bad and incorrect.

Comment: It appears to be from _Effective C: An Introduction to Professional C Programming - 
Robert C. Seacord_. Not a word about strict pointer aliasing. This is embarrassing, the book clearly didn't go through peer review by C experts. Another book to add to the black list...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is: you don't. And if you are a C beginner, you are out on deep waters since this is a rather advanced topic. My rule of thumb is that a beginner should *never* use the cast operator for any purpose, since there are so many pitfalls when doing so.

There are two problems going from a raw character byte array to a struct type:

- First there is alignment which the code addresses somewhat. But _Alignas etc only ensures that the buffer and the struct have the same alignment, ie start address. It does nothing for alignment of individual struct members and any padding the struct may contain internally. Such things are non-portable.
- Second, these kind of dirty casts are *undefined behavior* in the C language, meaning anything can happen. Including incorrect code getting generated, hardware exceptions getting thrown etc. Or it might just *seem* to work fine for now/this time/forever/until next full moon. [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

  (As it happens, you can go *from* a struct to a character byte array safely, but not the other way around.)

There's no quick fix to address both of these issues. If you are aware that a struct has padding bytes and where they are, then you could do something like:

```c
typedef union
{
  some_struct s;
  unsigned char buf [sizeof(some_struct)];
} some_union;
```

This solves the strict aliasing problems and initial alignment, but it doesn't solve the issue of individual struct members potentially having padding bytes. For that you'd need some non-standard means like `#pragma pack(1)`. Which in turn is problematic since padding is there for a reason and if you pack the struct you might not be able to access certain members as intended.

Structs are overall non-portable and unsuitable for things like close to the metal constructs like data communication protocols or register maps. The only truly portable way is to write a serialization/deserialization function which copies in/out of individual struct members one by one.

Comment: Regarding your first point, if the pointer is correctly aligned for the structure as a whole, then the addresses of all the members must be correctly aligned too as long as all the members have a fundamental alignment and do not have an alignment specifier specifying a non-fundamental alignment.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes but there will be padding bytes in order to guarantee that. And if the raw byte stream does not have corresponding dummy bytes matching that padding, then type punning between them will not work.

Comment: Later on you address the problem of alignment of structure members with externally defined protocol fields (i.e. serialization/deserialization). Perhaps in the first point you are discussing the possible non-alignment of structure members with some specific indices in the char array that are determined by some protocol, but as written, it reads like you are discussing the possible non-alignment of structure members relative to a pointer that is correctly aligned for the structure itself.

Comment: @IanAbbott Well, _Alignas doesn't do anything for individual struct members since their alignment is already handled automatically by the compiler (since C89, so nothing to do with C11). The problem with the OP's book is that they drop _Alignas as some sort of magic feature which will fix all problems in the code and we get the impression that if we only add this keyword, we can suddenly do wild & crazy type punning with dirty casts.